# how can i fix this: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript

trying to write a function that takes a string, and returns the string back with first letter of each word in capital. i am able to do so. But i keep on getting undefined value at my first index value in the iteration, tho the i have items in my list.

i wrote my function that takes a string parameter. i pass my parameter in to split using split(" ") method it so i can get an array of words. and when i created my forloop to go over all of them to be able to make each of their first letters Capital. now in the iteration, i create a variable to store the first index element converted into a string using the toString() method so i can later apply the toUpperCase() method on it

When i do a console.log() in the for loop i can see the elements converted all listed out (when i execute the function and pass a string to it)

But i do not understand why i get: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined...and this error points to the variable holding the element at index [i] when i am converting it to string in the forloop: var pickString = newStringList[i].toString()

```
function capitalizeLertters (letter) {
    var newStringList = letter.split(" ");
    // console.log(newStringList[0])
    var addAll = []

    for (var i = 0; i <= newStringList.length; i++) {
        console.log(newStringList[i])
        var pickString = newStringList[i].toString()
        // console.log(pickString)
        var finalString = pickString.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + pickString.slice(1)
        // console.log(finalString)
    }
    addAll.push(finalString)
    // console.log(addAll)
    return addAll
}

console.log(capitalizeLertters("js string exercises"))
```

This is my expected result: 
"Js String Exercises"

And these are the different console.log results

""js
Js
string
String
exercises
Exercises""

But my function does not execute in the end...it throws this:

"""learnJs.js:100 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
    at capitalizeLertters (learnJs.js:100)
    at learnJs.js:110"""

Comment: The `for` loop condition should be `<` not `<=`. Also there's no reason to call `.toString()` on something that's already a string.

Comment: Also the `.push()` needs to be *inside* the loop, not outside.

Answer (score 1):

So

1. You don't need `toString()` on a String
2. The for loop crashes at the last element because you should stop at `length -1` or simply replace `<=` with `<`.
3. You are calling `addAll` after the loop, so it only adds the last element.
4. You are returning an array and I assume you want the String, so you can use `join()` on the array.

```js
function capitalizeLertters (letter) {
    var newStringList = letter.split(" ");    
    var addAll = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < newStringList.length; i++) {         
        var pickString = newStringList[i];           
        var finalString = pickString.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + pickString.slice(1);
        addAll.push(finalString);
    }
          
    return addAll.join(" ");
}

console.log(capitalizeLertters("js string exercises"))
```

Comment: All perfectly clear. Nice Insight. Now working. So based on your point 2, the undefined was coming from the 4th element created by the <= sign? As in one more element created out of the fact that now: i = 3 <= newStringList.length (thus creating the 4ht element?)

Comment: @vially yes. Check the console output of your code. It printed
`js`, `string`, `exercises`, `undefined`, in this order. Thus, it was correctly iterating through the elements and printing them, and only after throwing the error. If the error was on the 1st element you wouldn't have seen the rest of the code working

Comment: @vially consider marking an answer as the accepted one in order to flag the question as answered. See here ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

please check the modifications

- push() method should be inside the loop.
- you are looping from index 0, thats why you need to use < instead of <=
- finally need to use join method to get string from array

**Solution**:

```
function capitalizeLertters (letter) {
    var newStringList = letter.split(" ");
    // console.log(newStringList[0])
    var addAll = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < newStringList.length; i++) {
        console.log(newStringList[i]);
        var pickString = newStringList[i];
        // console.log(pickString)
        var finalString = pickString.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + pickString.slice(1);
        // console.log(finalString)
        addAll.push(finalString);
    }
    // console.log(addAll)
    return addAll.join(" ");
}

capitalizeLertters("js string exercises");
```

Answer (score 1):

An array starts with the index number 0. The length of newStringList is 3. If you give a less than (<) then 'i' will go like 0("js"), 1("string"), 2("exercises"). If you give a less than equal (<=) it will go like 0("js"), 1("string"), 2("exercises"), 3(undefined).

```
  function capitalizeLertters (letter) {
  var newStringList = letter.split(" ");

  var addAll = ""

  for (var i = 0; i < newStringList.length; i++) {

  var pickString = newStringList[i].toString()

  var finalString = pickString.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + pickString.slice(1)
  addAll += finalString
  if(i != newStringList.length-1){
    addAll +=" "
  }
}


return addAll
}

console.log(capitalizeLertters("js string exercises"))
```